# git. Поддержка в актуальном состоянии файла на разных ветках

Tags: git, git-branch

Есть две ветки: условный `master` и, скажем, `branch2`. Большая часть файлов в ветках различна: названия совпадают, содержание нет. В обоих ветвях есть файл `README.md` (на стадии написания), содержание которого нужно держать общим для двух ветвей. Предполагается работать с двумя ветками, постоянно внося в них изменения и держать `README.md` в актуальном состоянии. Как это реализовать? Вносить изменения на одной из ветвей, копировать содержание `README.md` и переключаться на другую кажется не лучшим решением

Comment: Держать *README.md* в отдельной ветке, которую подмёрдживать и туда, и сюда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-Git-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0#r_rebase_cherry_pick)

```
git checkout branch2
```

Редактируете ТОЛЬКО `README.md` и комитите только его

```
git commit -m "New edition of readme"
[branch2 463dc4f] New edition of readme
```

после переходите в мастер

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick 463dc4f
Finished one cherry-pick.
[master]: created a0a41a9: "New edition of readme"
```

В мастер добавится только этот коммит. Дальше можете продолжать править branch2

Answer (score 1):

Смысл файла `README.md` в том, что он отражает состояние текущей версии.

Когда вы переходите на другую ветку, то в ней нет тех изменений которые есть в ветке `master`. Лучшей стратегией будет писать в `README.md` актуальное относительно каждой ветки. А при слияние веток сольётся и содержимое `README.md`